# How do I change App catalog for a web application?

Tags: sharepoint-addin, central-administration

In Central Administration, I created an app catalog for my Web application at an URL: `https://mysharepointsite/sites/appcatalog`

When I click the link and try to access the App catalog, I get errors that the App catalog site is not working (our custom master page is missing etc.).

Can I simply delete the created site collection in CA and then assign a new App catalog url in app catalog settings? Or is there some other preferred way to change App catalog for a Web application?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, if you delete the existing app catalog site collection then when you revisit the management page you will be presented with the option to choose a new one.